# Tunning Method Is Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity Game development .. I was following https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character?playlist=17144

Did everything same but,

I want the player object to rotate towards the mouse pointer. But it's not rotating towards mouse pointer..

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 movement;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    int floormask;
    float camraylength = 100f;
    float speed = 10f;



    void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        floormask = LayerMask.GetMask("floor");
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        moving(h, v);
        tunning();
        animationz(h, v);
    }
    void moving(float h, float v)
    {
        movement = new Vector3(h, 0, v);
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }
    void tunning()
    {
        Ray camray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit floorhit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(camray,out floorhit, camraylength, floormask))
        {
            Vector3 playertomouse = floorhit.point - transform.position;
            playertomouse.y = 0f;
            Quaternion newrotate = Quaternion.LookRotation(playertomouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newrotate); 
        }

    }
    void animationz(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);
    }
}
```

The tunning() method is in the above code

If anything more you want then please comment. Thank you for the help...

Comment: "But it's not working"... So, we are supposed to figure out what's not working?

Comment: xD... I mean it's not rotating towards the mouse pointer...

Comment: And I don't know where is the problem @Programmer

Comment: You need to give us more info. I can only guess. Make sure you have only one main camera tagged as MainCamera. If its not that just give us more info. Any errors in the console?

Comment: the scene file https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvxsfoqi6qa8ncj/main.unity?dl=0 @GregLukosek and no error in console

Comment: Sending scene file? really? #facePalm

Comment: Noone here is able to help. You need to provide more information, dont send scene file, its useless on its own. Dont send whole Unity Project. We are here to answer questions not to provide support for lazy who dont want to spend 10 minutes writing detailed description for others to be able to help

Comment: I am new to unity idk where is the problem.. This script worked correctly in unityy 4... @GregLukosek

Comment: And when i ask question to view the gameobject configs people ask me for the scene file sometimes that's why i sent :(

Comment: i'm noob..........

Comment: provide more info. what happens when you move the mouse? any errors you see? warnings? have you debug.log something? figured out anything yet?

Comment: maybe floor should be Floor?

Comment: still nt working :( and when i run i only see the animation no rotation...  And nothing in console too :( @Bijan

Comment: when you say its not rotating towards the mouse, is it rotating at all? away from the mouse? Be explicit as possible

Comment: given your information I have no clue! give some info dude!

Comment: Not it's not rotating at alll .. I mean that script is not making any change @BrettReinhard

Comment: Do u think the script is right ? @Bijan

Comment: it would be nice to see the code for Physics.Raycast(camray,out floorhit, camraylength, floormask), since no errors have been thrown I am guessing that this method is returning false and never executes any code within the if. A quick and dirty way of checking would be to use: if(!Physics.Raycast(camray,out floorhit, camraylength, floormask))

Comment: @BuckyĎroid additionally, are other methods being run? i.e. FixedUpdate()? If you were to put the same code in FixedUpdate() into Update() would it still work?

Comment: The code seems right but that's normally not enough to say. try putting Debug.Log(...) everywhere and find out where exactly is the problem. my guess is that raycast does not hit

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check several stuff to find the source of the problem:

- You need to make sure you are using a Quad not a Plane and that the correct face is upwards
- Make sure the layer of the quad is "floor" (it's case sensitive)
- Make sure the camera is not further than the 100f of the ray you are casting
- And finally add a Debug.Log() inside the if condition to check if the ray hits the floor at all.